# count number of tags in a couchdb document

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a simple document design that is something like this...

```
{
  _id: "something", 
  type: "post", 
  title: "A Title",
  content: "A Blog Content",
  tags: ["newtag", "oldtag", "bluetag", "youtag"]
}
```

So each document will have an array of "tags". What I am trying to do is create a view that will count how many times a tag is used. So it would search all docs, emit the tags, and then add them up by key. Example...

```
Doc1
{
  _id: "something",
  type: "post",
  title: "A title",
  content: "Blog Content",
  tags: ["oldtag", "newtag", "bluetag", "youtag"]
}
Doc2
{
  _id: "domethin",
  type: "post",
  title: "another title",
  content: "another post",
  tags: ["oldtag", "notag", "whytag"]
}
```

Given that I would need something that would have "oldtag" : 2, "notag": 1, "whytag": 1, ...

But I can't seem to figure it out. I tried using....

```
"map": "function(doc) {if(doc.type == 'post') { for(var i = 0, l doc.tags.length; i < l; i++) { emit(doc.tags[i], 1); } } }",
"reduce": "_count"
```

but that just gives me...

> {"rows":[
>   {"key":null,"value":20}
>   ]}

Does anyone know how to do this? I am pretty stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had invalid javascript in your view.

var i=0; `l doc.tags` l should be assign to doc.tags.length

See the fixed version  :

```
{
  "_id": "_design/tagcount",
  "_rev": "1-d14c9d06e652ad23df1044ffbca9d85f",
  "views": {
    "count": {
      "reduce": "_count",
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  if(doc.type== 'post') { \n    for(var i = 0, l= doc.tags.length; i < l; i++) { emit(doc.tags[i], 1); } } \n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

Also, you need to specify the reduce :

`http://localhost:5984/<db>/_design/<design>/_view/<viem>?limit=20&reduce=true&group=true`

Note: Replace the <value> by their real value.

Comment: Is there a way to make them return ordered? So that the "tags" that are used more are returned first?

Comment: Actually, sorting in map and reduce is by key only. Other than in memory sort, you can give a try to Mango Query.